# BB10 cascades linking of contacts

Tags: blackberry-cascades

I developing an application on BB10 cascades.

I have contact A with attribute 'attr1' and contact B with attribute 'attr2'.

Next, i link contacts A and B.

When i receive contactdetails [Cascades Api](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__pim__contacts__contactservice.html#function-contactdetails-contactid), it returns a contact A with attributes  'attr1' and 'attr2'.

How i can detect that attribute 'attr1' belongs to a contact A and attribute 'attr2' belongs to a contact B?

Comment: I thought the purpose of linking contacts was to make them indistinguishable. What is the use-case for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the merged accounts using [mergedContacts](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__pim__contacts__contactservice.html#function-mergedcontacts-contactid) and then check the attributes for each contact it returns.